# Changing the orientation of tabbar controller Forcefully

Tags: iphone, controller, orientation, tabbar

Hai.

In my iphone app i won't to change my tabbar orientation to landscape or portrait with out rotating the device, such that when i am pressing rotate button whole tabbar controller need to rotate for either landscape or portrait mode.

can any one please give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change orientation, try changing the frame.

```
void convertPortraitToLandscap()
{
  CGPoint temp;
  temp = [touch locationInView:self];
  touchPoint.x = temp.y;
  touchPoint.y = 320 - temp.x;
}
```

The above code convert points from portrait to landscape... similarly try changing the frame of the view.